# Is there a way to get German text to speech in festival?

Tags: festival, text-to-speech

Searching for info about German text to speech, I came across a "Dialog-based Human-Technology Interaction by Coordinated Analysis and Generation of Multiple Modalities", as well as [this page](http://ttssamples.syntheticspeech.de/), which I can't really parse. I mean, it *mentions* festival several times...

Hm...

I've loaded voices and languages into `festival` using `apt-get`, for Finnish, Spanish, Czech, and [Russian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=festvox-ru).

I've also loaded voices into `festival` by `wget`-ing some [files](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=677277) and renaming them in accordance with festival's directory structure.

So... is there a way to use either of those two methods to enable German text to speech on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I can assure you, the page you mentioned lists several developments of german voices on top of festival.

But you need to follow the link to the several commercial or academic offerings, and some are in german only. Maybe MBROLA voices are worth looking at for your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

The *Institute for Natural Language Processing* in Stuttgart offers an [open source distribution for festival](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/institut/arbeitsgruppen/phonetik/synthesis/festival_opensource.en.html). You have to fill in your name in the form and they will send you a link to the files.

There is only a [demo page](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/institut/arbeitsgruppen/phonetik/synthesis/synthesis_demo.en.html), where you can try the system with arbitrary text.

Comment: These web links are dead.